# When is a graph a $\operatorname{CAT}(\kappa)$ space?

Tags: graph-theory, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry

Let $G:=(E,V,W)$ be a weighted graph and let $d_G$ be its graph metric, defined by on any two edges $e_1,e_2\in E$ by
$$
d_G(e_1,e_2)\triangleq 
\inf_{\gamma}\, \sum_{v\in \gamma} W(v),\qquad\tag{0}\label{0}
$$
where the infimum is taken over all sequences of vertices $\gamma=(v_1,\dots,v_t)$ connecting $e_1$ to $e_2$; where $W:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the *weight function* defined on unweighted graph $(E,V)$.

In Ballmann's book [Lectures on spaces of nonpositive curvature](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/hwbllmnn/archiv/NPC0606.pdf) conditions are given which guarantee that $d_G$ has non-positive curvature (*[in the sense of Alexandrov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_space)*); namely, there is some $c>0$ satisfying:
$$
\inf_{v}\, W(v)\geq c.\tag{1}\label{1}
$$
My question is, when is $(E,d_G)$ a $\operatorname{CAT}(\kappa)$ space, for some $\kappa\in \mathbb{R}$?

---

My hypothesis is that there exist some partition $C_1,\dotsc,C_N$ of $E$ into open balls such that \eqref{1} holds; where the infimum in \eqref{0} is taken over all paths $\gamma$ contained in $C_i$; where $e_1,e_2\in C_i$.

Comment: My rough guess is that a metric graph with smallest cycle of length $r$ is CAT($\kappa$) iff the round 2-sphere with equator of size $r$ (i.e., radius $r/2\pi$) has curvature $\le\kappa$. But I'm really unsure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generalized Cartan--Hadamard theorem states that a length space is CAT(1) if it is locally CAT(1) + any closed curve of length $<2{\cdot}\pi$ is null-homotopic in class of curves of length $<2{\cdot}\pi$.

If the space is a graph, then the latter is equivalent to saying that any cycle has length at least $2{\cdot}\pi$.

Comment: I can't manage to track down this generalized Cartan-Hadamard theorem; where could I find it/does it have some other name?

Comment: @Carl_Petterson See p. 119 here https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.08539v1.